# Using subquery within IF condition

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb-10.3

Hello i am having a weird problem currently i have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `txt_campaign_message` `cm`
         LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign` `c` ON c.id = cm.campaign_id
         LEFT JOIN `txt_message` `m` ON m.id = cm.message_id
         LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign_subscriber` `cs` ON cs.campaign_id = cm.campaign_id
WHERE ((`c`.`user_id` = 2) AND (`m`.`message_type` = 'blast') AND (`c`.`active` = 1))
  AND (NOT (`cs`.`subscriber_id` IS NULL))
  AND cs.subscriber_id = (
    (IF
        (cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL,
         (SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
           from `txt_campaign_subscriber` cs1
           WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
         ),
         (cs.subscriber_id)
        )
    )
  )
  AND (`cm`.`campaign_id` = 1386)
```

which gave me an error

> Sub-query returns multiple rows

and i changed the query part `AND cs.subscriber_id = (IF` to use `IN` rather than `=` before the condition like below

```
SELECT *
FROM `txt_campaign_message` `cm`
         LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign` `c` ON c.id = cm.campaign_id
         LEFT JOIN `txt_message` `m` ON m.id = cm.message_id
         LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign_subscriber` `cs` ON cs.campaign_id = cm.campaign_id
WHERE ((`c`.`user_id` = 2) AND (`m`.`message_type` = 'blast') AND (`c`.`active` = 1))
  AND (NOT (`cs`.`subscriber_id` IS NULL))
  AND cs.subscriber_id IN (
    (IF
        (cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL,
         (SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
           from `txt_campaign_subscriber` cs1
           WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
         ),
         (cs.subscriber_id)
        )
    )
  )
  AND (`cm`.`campaign_id` = 1386)
```

But the error remains the same, to my surprise if i remove the if condition and just use the sub query all runs fine

```
SELECT *
FROM `txt_campaign_message` `cm`
         LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign` `c` ON c.id = cm.campaign_id
         LEFT JOIN `txt_message` `m` ON m.id = cm.message_id
         LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign_subscriber` `cs` ON cs.campaign_id = cm.campaign_id
WHERE ((`c`.`user_id` = 2) AND (`m`.`message_type` = 'blast') AND (`c`.`active` = 1))
  AND (NOT (`cs`.`subscriber_id` IS NULL))
  AND cs.subscriber_id IN (
         (SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
           from `txt_campaign_subscriber` cs1
           WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
         )
  )
  AND (`cm`.`campaign_id` = 1386)
```

and when i add the condition back it starts throwing the same error, what am i doing wrong or what do i need to change if i am using the IF condition for the sub-query, i already changed the `=` to `IN` as i needed multiple rows to be compared.

I am using `MariaDB (10.3)` where i am facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the IF statement cannot contain a set, it needs to be a scalar. Let's illustrate with:

```
create table T (x int not null);
insert into T (x) values (1),(2);
-- invalid since `SELECT x FROM T` is a set of rows
SELECT * FROM T WHERE 1 IN ( IF (1=1, SELECT x FROM T, 1) );
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f470a8b68c2ab954455bfc81b8f6ee2b)

Let's see if your query can be reformulated (I changed it slightly to make it more readable):

```
SELECT *
FROM txt_campaign_message cm
LEFT JOIN txt_campaign c 
    ON c.id = cm.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN txt_message m 
    ON m.id = cm.message_id
LEFT JOIN txt_campaign_subscriber cs 
    ON cs.campaign_id = cm.campaign_id
WHERE c.user_id = 2 
  AND m.message_type = blast 
  AND c.active = 1
  -- AND cs.subscriber_id IS NOT NULL, redundant and can be removed 
  AND cs.subscriber_id IN (
    IF (cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL
       , (SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
          FROM txt_campaign_subscriber cs1
          WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) 
                                        AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
         )
       , cs.subscriber_id
       )
  )
  AND cm.campaign_id = 1386;
```

This is the problematic part:

```
AND cs.subscriber_id IN (
    IF (cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL
       , (SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
          FROM txt_campaign_subscriber cs1
          WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) 
                                        AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
         )
       , cs.subscriber_id
       )
  )
```

Two cases:

```
a) cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL

AND cs.subscriber_id IN (
       SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
       FROM txt_campaign_subscriber cs1
       WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) 
                                     AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
)


b) cm.date_range_from IS NULL

cs.subscriber_id = cs.subscriber_id

i.e. TRUE
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(
AND cs.subscriber_id IN (
       SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
       FROM txt_campaign_subscriber cs1
       WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) 
                                     AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
    )
AND cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL
)
OR cm.date_range_from IS NULL
```

All and all we end up with:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    txt_campaign_message cm
LEFT JOIN txt_campaign c ON
    c.id = cm.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN txt_message m ON
    m.id = cm.message_id
LEFT JOIN txt_campaign_subscriber cs ON
    cs.campaign_id = cm.campaign_id
WHERE c.user_id = 2 
  AND m.message_type = blast 
  AND c.active = 1
  AND (
      cs.subscriber_id IN (
          SELECT cs1.subscriber_id
          FROM txt_campaign_subscriber cs1
          WHERE DATE(cs.created_at) BETWEEN DATE(cm.date_range_from) 
                                        AND DATE(cm.date_range_to)
        ) AND cm.date_range_from IS NOT NULL
      OR 
      cm.date_range_from IS NULL
  ) 
  AND cm.campaign_id = 1386;
```

Totally untested, but it should give you an idea

You may also consider rewriting the in-predicate as a JOIN

Answer (score 0):

(I need formatting not available in a Comment.)

`DATE(...)` is not sargable.  There is probably no reason to use the `DATE` function; simply do

```
cs.created_at  BETWEEN  cm.date_range_from  AND  cm.date_range_to
```

But, that won't really help -- comparing something to a range computed from other columns cannot be optimized.

For this:

```
AND (NOT (`cs`.`subscriber_id` IS NULL))
AND cs.subscriber_id = ...
```

The first test is unnecessary.  The second will fail if it is `NULL`.

A note on `LEFT`:

```
LEFT JOIN `txt_campaign` `c` ...
...
WHERE ((`c`.`user_id` = 2)
```

The `LEFT` says that there might not be a row in txt_campaign; the `WHERE` says there must be.  Remove the word `LEFT`.